# pam_unix(sshd:auth): auth could not identify password for [admin] - sshd[6968]?

Tags: ssh, pam

Why is the following log produced?

```
pam_unix(sshd:auth): auth could not identify password for [admin] - sshd[6968]
```

Is it because of a timeout, or is there some other reason?

Comment: ADD : One of the pam libraries in the sshd pam config file is making the password to be null and hence pam_unix does not get any password for authentication. Problem solved by editing the custom pam library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the pam modules have made the password null and it is passed to the pam_unix. Once I fixed it, it started working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Please, what module made the password null? I am seeing a very similar error.

Comment: @MiloGertjejansen PAM allows us to write our own modules and plug them into it. So one of my custom module was making it null.

Answer (score -1):

Check your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. If this user `admin` is listed as **`DenyUsers`**. Comment the particular line and restart the `sshd` service.

Comment: `DenyUsers` controls what SSH itself does. It does *not* control PAM.